# Showing a loading background color responsive when downloading an image

Tags: html, css

In my app I obtain an image and the size with a fetch from a JSON. I would like to fill the gap that leaves the image while is loading.

The problem is that, if I make a `div` that fills the gap with a fixed `width` and `height`, the filling `div` is not responsive (in the case of the image the style is `height: auto; max-height: XXXpx;`) **How can I make it responsive without loosing the width / height proportion?**

**IMPORTANT: My objective is to make it work with any width and height combination, without losing the ratio / proportion.**

---

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of my issue. You will check that the `div` has a fixed size that overflows when the width or the height of the window is less than `256px` but the image is responsive. **How can I make the `div` responsive too, without losing the proportion?**

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <!--
      This div contains the image. By default, the div uses the `container`
      class (detailed below) that has a fixed width and height that is
      the same size of the image. The class will be removed in other to make the
      image "responsive" when the image download finished. 
    -->
    <div
      id="container"
      class="container"
    >
      <!--
        This image uses the `image` class which has the needed styles to make it responsive.
        In addition, it will fire "removeDummyClass()" when is loaded.
      -->
      <img
        class="image"
        src="https://sftextures.com/texture/2574/0/2578/dog-foot-pad-on-white-snow-frozen-ground-dark-footprint-sign-icy-cold-winter-pattern-seamless-texture-256x256.jpg"
        onload="removeDummyClass()"
      />
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      // With this function, we will remove class that has a dummy image
      // (in this case, a div with a background-color)
      const removeDummyClass = () => {
        document
          .getElementById('container')
          .classList
          .remove('container')
      }
    </script>

    <style>
      .container {
        background-color: red;
        width: 256px;
        height: 256px;
      }

      .image {
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I'm adding some screenshots, **not for debugging, just making the issue clear**.

The first load, the div overflows because the width and height is set manually.

[image: div overflows]

Then, when the image is loaded, the image will be resized without losing the proportion between width and height.

[image: image responsive]

Comment: We don't debug screenshots. Please update your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Do you mean file size or the size of the image? That would be interesting to know. If you got the size of the image, add a div which fits the size and display a stock image or grey background.

Comment: @j08691 I have added a reproducible example with more explanation of my issue, thanks both for your attention.

Comment: @davidev I mean the size of the image, I have added a reproducible example to make it clear, you will check that the div isn't responsive (window with width / height less than 256px will overflow) but the image will resize when is loaded. I would like to use the same responsive shape on the div too.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am still trying to understand the issue. Your are loading a image, and the place where the image will be displayed shouldn't be collapse, it should have a specific size? Which one? Then when the image is loaded, should it be fitted into the div perfectly - or should the div change its size relative to the image size?

Comment: @davidev In short, I would like to load a div of the same responsive size that will have when loaded with a colored background. What I mean is that, if the window is greater than the image original sizes, the div should have the same size as the image (256x256). On the other hand, if the image will load in a smaller window (100px for example), I would like the div to have the same responsive size that the image will have when loaded (in this case, 100x100).

Comment: So essentially you want an image placeholder that has the same width/height ratio as the image? Why not apply the `image` class to the `<div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieve it using an SVG filled with a rect with the height and width expected, then `onload` remove the SVG with `display: none` and show the image with `display: block`.

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <style>
      .image {
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 256px;
      }

      .image-final {
        display: none;
      }

      .image-dummy-rect {
        fill: red;
      }
    </style>

    <div>
      <svg
        id="image-dummy"
        class="image"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 256 256"
      >
        <rect
          id="image-dummy-rect"
          class="image-dummy-rect"
          width="256"
          height="256"
        />
      </svg>
      <img
        id="image-final"
        class="image image-final"
        src="https://sftextures.com/texture/2574/0/2578/dog-foot-pad-on-white-snow-frozen-ground-dark-footprint-sign-icy-cold-winter-pattern-seamless-texture-256x256.jpg"
        onload="removeDummyClass()"
      />
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      const removeDummyClass = () => {
        document.getElementById('image-dummy').style.display = 'none'
        document.getElementById('image-final').style.display = 'block'
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using a bit of **javascript**: 
Hide the content of the page and show your background item. 
When the body is not ready run a script interval every 1 second (you can handle this on your proper way) and when the page body is ready display it changing the property of the page `display:none` to `display:block`

```js
function onReady(callback) {
   var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 1000);

   function checkReady() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) 
    {
     window.clearInterval(intervalID);
     callback.call(this);
    }
   }
  }

  function show(id, value) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
  }

  onReady(function () {
   show('page', true);
   show('loading', false);
  });
```

```css
#page {
   display: none;
  }

  #loading {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 100;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background-image: url("URL_TO_YOUR_IMAGE");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
  }

  .loading-page {
   background: #72c3c9; /*The background color*/
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
   -ms-flex-pack: center;
   justify-content: center;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
   -ms-flex-align: center;
   align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="page" style="display:none">
    <!-- YOUR PAGE CONTENT GOES HERE -->
 </div> 
 <div id="loading" class="loading-page">  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but it doesn't respect the ratio of the image, because it uses `vh` and `vw`.